# DC js charts, crossfilter not filtering on click

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

*Updated with more relevant code.
*Updated again: removing chart groupings results in this error: "Unable to get property 'classed' of undefined or null reference dc.js (5575,9)". I am using dc 3.0.11.

I have an issue where my dc charts are not filtering each other upon clicking a selection on a chart. It does work if I call a function to explicitly do so, but I would like to avoid that.

This is my general approach:

- I do have dc.css included (if that matters)
- my crossfilter ndx and dimensions are correct

I am defining my charts WITHOUT .on renderlet (is this the reason?)

```
        var masterData = [];





$(document).ready(function () { //UPDATED CODE START


var siteurl = 'site';
var ItemCount= GetItemCount(siteurl, 'list');
createRestUrl(siteurl,ItemCount,'list');

});  // UPDATED CODE END



function GetItemCount(siteurl, ListName){
var ItemCount='';
$.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ListName+"')/ItemCount", 
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        ItemCount = data.d.ItemCount;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
return ItemCount;   

}   // GetItemCount END


function createRestUrl(siteurl, ItemCount, ListName) {


    var listServiceUrl = siteurl+ "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName + "')/Items";


//Rest call to process each items of list
    $.when(processList(listServiceUrl,ItemCount)).done(function () { 

console.log("FINISHED");
console.log("--------");
console.log(masterData);

    var ndx = crossfilter(masterData),
        clientMgr = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.clientMgr}),                        
        otherTeammates = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.otherTeammates}),
        topic = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.topic}),
        status = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.status}),
        team = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.team}),
        requester = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.requester}),
        requesterBusiness = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.requesterBusiness}),
        submitted = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.submitted}),
        clientMgrGroup = clientMgr.group(),
        otherTeammatesGroup = otherTeammates.group(),
        topicGroup = topic.group(),
        statusGroup = status.group(),
        teamGroup = team.group(),
        requesterGroup = requester.group(),
        requesterBusinessGroup = requesterBusiness.group(),
        submittedGroup = submitted.group();

        var teamChart = dc.rowChart("#team_chart", "team");
        var clientMgrChart = dc.pieChart("#mgr_chart", "mgr");
        var statusChart = dc.pieChart("#status_chart", "status");
        var requesterChart = dc.rowChart("#requester_chart", "request");
        var requesterBusinessChart = dc.pieChart("#requesterBusiness_chart", "requestBusiness");
        var timeSelect = dc.lineChart("#time_chart", "time");
        var topicChart = dc.pieChart("#topic_chart", "topic");
        var teamNum = dc.numberDisplay("#teamNum", "teamNum");

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
        return dat;
        }

        var thisDay = new Date();
        var todayMinSix = thisDay.addDays(-30);
        var todayPlusSix = thisDay.addDays(30);

        teamChart
        .dimension(team)
        .group(teamGroup)
        .width(800)
        .height(200)
        .transitionDuration(3000)
        .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value })
            .elasticX(true)
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]))
        .colors('#58D3F7')

        //teamNum
        //.valueAccessor(function(d) { return d})
        //.formatNumber(d3.format())
        //.group(teamGroup)

        clientMgrChart
        .dimension(clientMgr)
        .group(clientMgrGroup)
        .width(300)
        .height(300)
        .transitionDuration(3000)

            statusChart
        .dimension(status)
        .group(statusGroup)
        .height(200)
        .width(500)
        .innerRadius(95)
        .transitionDuration(3000)
        .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["02 - Work-In-Progress", "01 - Pending Initial Review"])
                       .range(['#58D3F7', '#2E9AFE']))

        requesterChart
            .dimension(requester)
            .group(requesterGroup)
            .height(200)
            .width(800)
            .gap(10)
        .transitionDuration(3000)
            .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value })
            .elasticX(true)
        .colors('#F78181')
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]));

        requesterBusinessChart
        .dimension(requesterBusiness)
        .group(requesterBusinessGroup)
        .height(300)
        .width(300)
        .innerRadius(117)
        .transitionDuration(3000)
        .colors('#F78181')

        topicChart
        .dimension(topic)
        .group(topicGroup)
        .height(200)
        .width(500)
        .innerRadius(95)
        .transitionDuration(3000)
        .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["New Report / Interface", "General Support", "One-Time Data Set", "Recurring Data Set", "Modify Existing Report / Interface", "Production Issue"])
                       .range(['#F5A9A9', '#F78181', '#FA5858', '#F6CECE', '#F8E0E0', "#FBEFEF"]))

        timeSelect
        .width(1700)
            .height(150)
            .dimension(submitted)
            .group(submittedGroup)
            .transitionDuration(1000)
            .elasticY(true)
            .renderArea(true)
            .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([todayMinSix, thisDay]))
            .xUnits(d3.timeDays)
            .mouseZoomable(false)
            .xAxis();

        teamChart.render(); 
        statusChart.render();
        requesterChart.render();
        topicChart.render();


});
}

//Step 3: Rest call to process each items of list
function processList(nextUrl,ItemCount) {

    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    if (nextUrl == undefined) {
        dfd.resolve();
        return;
    }

getJSONDataFromUrl(nextUrl).done(function (listItems) {

        TotalItemCount = TotalItemCount+listItems.d.results.length;
        console.log("getJSON called");
        var items = listItems.d.results;
            var next = listItems.d.__next;

            $.when(processList(next,ItemCount)).done(function (){
            dfd.resolve();
            });

    $.each(items, function(index, obj){
        items = {};
        items.clientMgr = obj.ClientMgr;                         //Assigned To - might not be the right field
        items.otherTeammates = obj.OtherTeammatesEngaged;        //Assigned To - might not be the right field
        items.topic = obj.Topic;
        items.status = obj.Status;
        items.team = obj.Team; 
        items.requester = obj.RequesterLOB;
        items.submitted = obj.Submitted;
        items.requesterBusiness = obj.RequesterBusinessGroup;
        console.log("looping through each");

        var convert = new Date(items.submitted);
        items.submittedConvert = moment(convert).format('L');
        items.submitted = convert;  

        var assignName = items.clientMgr;
        items.clientMgr = assignName;       

        masterData.push(items);
        console.log(items.requesterBusiness);
        console.log(items.status);
    });  //.each END



}); // getJSONDataFromUrl END

return dfd.promise();

}   // processList END
```

I had this working long ago, but as the project became more complex, something broke along the way.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions related to the charting library. [dc] is a venerable old Unix "desk calculator". :-)

Comment: We'd need more code (or preferably a running example) to diagnose this without a lot of guessing. The most common reasons charts won't filter each other are 1) they are in different chartGroups (optional second parameter to chart constructors) or 2) they are on the same dimension or 3) (unlikely but possible) they are on different crossfilter instances.  No, you should not need a renderlet for ordinary operation.

Comment: I can update the post with all the code if that helps. It's just a lot.

The charts were not defined with the same group, but I tried making them all part of the same group and removing the group entirely from those declarations and it still didn't work. The charts are also not on the same dimension.

I'll edit my code above to give more details.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to have all your charts on different chartGroups. Pretty uncommon to specify the second parameter on charts at all, unless you have multiple crossfilter instances. 

Charts will only filter in the same chart group (that's what chart groups do). What were you trying to do there?

Comment: I think it's a product of me being confused for a while among other things like trying to piggyback off coworkers' code :)

It makes sense that I don't need chart groupings for this. So I removed them, but then I get the error "Unable to get property 'classed' of undefined or null reference dc.js (5575,9)"

This happens right when I click on a chart, so it does appear that the filtering is being attempted.

Comment: Getting warmer. :-D Could you add the error, version of dc.js you are using and the source line in dc.js that is crashing to your question?

Comment: A guess: sometimes there are weird crashes when a chart is created but not initialized or rendered. Redraw happens but the chart isn't there and boom. Rather than calling `chart.render()` on each chart individually, it might be safer (and quicker) just to call `dc.renderAll()` after they are all initialized.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I'll update the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the error refers to the use of `.classed()` a few lines up from 5575. Here are the lines leading up to 5575:

```
    if (d3.sum(_chart.data(), _chart.cappedValueAccessor)) {
        pieData = pie(_chart.data());
        _g.classed(_emptyCssClass, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise we'd be getting NaNs, so override
        // note: abuse others for its ignoring the value accessor
        pieData = pie([{key: _emptyTitle, value: 1, others: [_emptyTitle]}]);
        _g.classed(_emptyCssClass, true);
    }

if (_g) {
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/3.0.11/dc.js#L5565-L5575

So (except for the line number being a little off) it's a good guess that `_g` is null.

As I noted in my comment above, this probably indicates that the chart was redrawn before it was rendered. This can happen if you create a chart but don't render it. Rendering initializes things like the scale and parent elements like the `<g>` that holds the chart.

When you create a chart, you either specify a chart group or the default chart group is selected for you. The chart is registered in that group, and when any chart in the group is filtered, *all the charts are redrawn*.

In your code above, you render specific charts (4 of them), but there are many more charts which you initialize but don't render (8). In particular, all of the pie charts are rendered except for `clientMgrChart`. When you later click on a chart, it's likely that chart crashes when it tries to redraw.

It would be [nice if dc.js implemented a more helpful error for this case](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1523) since you currently have to guess "hmm, null, guess something hasn't been set up right" and know that render must happen before redraw.

**Note**: it's more robust to initialize the charts and then call

```
dc.renderAll();
```

instead of rendering each one manually.

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick!

Thank you so much for the help. I learned a lot from this exchange :)

I have one more issue with this now - the numberDisplay (teamNum) isn't redrawing when I select a filter. Is there something wrong with the way I've written it (it is no longer in a separate chart group)?

Comment: With the code above I would expect the numberDisplay to change when any chart is filtered **except for `teamChart`**. This is because [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters). You'd have to define another team dimension if you want `teamGroup` to observe filters on the existing `team` dimension.

Comment: That said, it usually makes more sense to attach your number display to `crossfilter.groupAll` not `dimension.group` - since it only displays a single value, it will show the largest value from a group, but it will show the single value of a groupAll.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your help so much! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note to others: With dc.js 3.1.2, my individual rowCharts would not animate themselves when clicked. The other charts in the crossfilter did animate.

Very confused, traced all the way through the dc.js call stack and learned a lot.

Ultimately, root cause for the failure was not having dc.css linked in my page's HTML.

Another good 'tell' that you don't have dc.css properly linked is that the rowChart vertical lines do not render.

**Screenshots**

rowChart With CSS - Clicking any of the bars DOES trigger animation.

[image: rowChart with CSS]

rowChart Without CSS - Clicking any of the bars does not trigger animation.

[image: rowChart without CSS]